# Buildroot - udev disables serial console

Tags: serial, buildroot

I have a custom buildroot image for RPi 0w. Initial experiments went well, however as soon as I added udev package to buildroot something strange happened to console output. I can see the whole log from booting and everything seems to get up without errors. At the end of the boot, I cannot input anything into serial (via putty) so I'm effectively locked away from the system.

I tried adding /etc/securetty file but it did not help. I have getty console enabled in menuconfig and in /etc/inittab, my cmdline.txt. looks like this:

```
root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootwait console=serial0,115200 console=tty1
```

Those settings worked previously, so I assume this has something to do with udev.

I assume I have to change something in configuration, but there is so much of it that I feel overwhelmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found solution here: http://buildroot-busybox.2317881.n4.nabble.com/BuildRoot-not-starting-with-Udev-td33140.html

Udev requires re configuring kernel because new DEVTMPFS is needed.